Why are some of the specified buttons missing from the CKEditor 5 toolbar?
I have an implementation of DecoupledEditor CKEditor 5 in my project:


<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/38.1.1/decoupled-document/ckeditor.js"></script>

DecoupledEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
                extraPlugins: [ MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin ],
                toolbar: {
                    items: [
                        'undo', 'redo',
                        '|', 'fontfamily', 'fontsize', 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor',
                        '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'subscript', 'superscript', 'code',
                        '|', 'alignment', 'specialCharacters',
                        'link', 'uploadImage', 'blockQuote', 'codeBlock', 'mediaEmbed', 'insertTable',
                        '|', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'todoList', 'outdent', 'indent'
                    ]
                }
            } )
            .then( editor => {
                const toolbarContainer = document.querySelector( '#editor-toolbar-container' );
                toolbarContainer.appendChild( editor.ui.view.toolbar.element );



But not all buttons are displayed in the toolbar.
There is no code, specialCharacters, codeBlock and so on.

It's the same if I use the ClassicEditor.
Why are these buttons missing and how do I install them?
Thanks!

Have you checked the CKEditor documentation?

You need to make sure you are using the right CKEditor build. The codeBlock and specialCharacters are not included by default in most CKEditor builds - for those builds you need to add the Pugin aswell. See https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/predefined-builds.html#list-of-plugins-included-in-the-ckeditor-5-predefined-builds

Thanks @nbokmans for the link! I'll try to dig in this direction.

I tried to implement super-build, but got 4 errors: 192:2792 CKEditorError: collaboration-missing-channelid. And how to fix it? )

collaboration is a commercial plugin, you need a license to run it. And the channelid has to be configured then according to your license probably.
